# Javascript: Show data in array if one element is showable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm just new at javascript and currently working with arrays and objects.

Can somebody help me to get the data if the searchble is true in columns.
I have columns in array

```
let columns = [
 {
   data: "id",
   searchable: false
 },
 {

   data: "first_name",
   searchable: true
 },
 {
   data: "last_name",
   searchable: true
 }
];
```

```
let filter = {
  target: columns, // if searhable is true
};
```

If I console log the filter. It will look like this.
**Result**:

```
{
target: [
  0: "first_name"
  1: "last_name"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner solution, with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const columns = [
 {
   data: "id",
   searchable: false
 },
 {

   data: "first_name",
   searchable: true
 },
 {
   data: "last_name",
   searchable: true
 }
];

const filter = {
  target: columns,
};

const result = columns.filter(column => column.searchable).map(column => column.data);
filter.target = result;

console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const columns = [{
    data: "id",
    searchable: false
  },
  {

    data: "first_name",
    searchable: true
  },
  {
    data: "last_name",
    searchable: true
  }
];


let filter = {
  target: []
};

for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  if (columns[i].searchable) {
    filter.target.push(columns[i].data);
  }
}
console.log(filter);
```